# How to generate a pdf reports with fromdate to todate using tcpdf

Tags: php, sql

i have generated a reports with pdf its working cool but i need to generate a reports with fromdate to todate using the form

This is my Code,

```
  function fetch_data()  
  {  
  $output = '';  
  $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "s22in_salon", "S22cs@1522", 
  "s22in_salondb");  
  $sql = "SELECT branchname,c_name,c_address,c_phone,servicename,attendername,date,intime,outime,paymenttype,amount
    FROM customerdetails";  
   $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);  
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
  {       
  $output .= '<tr>  
                      <td>'.$row["branchname"].'</td>  
                      <td>'.$row["date"].'</td>  
                     <td>'.$row["c_name"].'</td>  

                       <td>'.$row["c_address"].'</td>  
                       <td>'.$row["c_phone"].'</td>
                       <td>'.$row["attendername"].'</td>
                       <td>'.$row["paymenttype"].'</td>
                       <td>'.$row["amount"].'</td>
                 </tr>  
                      ';  
  }  
  return $output;  
  }
```

Comment: Add a `WHERE` clause to your query and use the `BETWEEN` operator. `FROM customerdetails WHERE ? between datestart and dateend`

Comment: I have html form with datestart and enddate how i can call that value in above code

Comment: Same thing just inverse. `FROM customerdetails WHERE Date between ? and ?` then bind the datestart as the first parameter and dateend as the second.

Comment: Ya i worked with your code its not showing a values in pdf

Comment: i am getting a plane pdf file without any datas

Comment: Can you update the code in the question?

Comment: now its working with the post dude thank you for your help@user3783243

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your SQL query with below one

```
 $sql = "SELECT branchname,c_name,c_address,c_phone,servicename,attendername,date,intime,outime,paymenttype,amount
    FROM customerdetails WHERE date BETWEEN '$fromDate' AND '$toDate' ";
```

Where $fromDate and $toDate will be your start and end date respectively

Comment: Good morning SQL injections.